# Populate a hash with JSON form API

Tags: json, ruby

Im trying to build a string and filling it with the results of a random JSON. Let me explain

I want a random JSON from the Star Wars API so I need to randomize the type(planets, people, starships) and the index.

So here is my code so far

```
data = { "planet": ["name",
                       "diameter",
                       "climate",
                       "rotation_period",
                       "orbital_period",
                       "population",
                       "terrain",
                       "résidants"],
            "species": ["name",
                        "language",
                        "classification",
                        "designation",
                        "homeworld"],
            "people": ["name",
                       "height",
                       "mass",
                       "birth_year"] }

    dataUrl = data.keys.sample

    number = rand 1..10


@response = JSON.parse(Faraday.get("https://swapi.co/api/#{dataUrl.to_s}/#{number}/?format=json").body)
```

Now... I need to build the string.

Before I used the hash, I was simply choose the type with a random number but I want to use less if statement

```
if type == 1
      height = @response["height"]
      mass = @response["mass"]
      birth_year = @response["birth_year"]
      text = "Some facts about #{name}. It has a height of #{height}centimeters and a mass of #{mass}kilograms. It was born in #{birth_year}."
    elsif type == 2
      classification = @response["classification"]
      language = @response["language"]
      text = "Some facts about the species #{name}. It is a #{classification}. It will answer you in #{language}"
    else
      population = @response["population"]
      climate = @response["climate"]
      diameter = @response["diameter"]
      text = "Some facts about the planet #{name}. It has a population of #{population} habitants and a climate #{climate}. Its diameter is #{diameter} "
    end
```

Can you give me some pointers how to build the string text the more efficient way possible and filling the value of hash depending of the @response I get.

After that, I'm sending to Watson Text To speech function so I can play it in my ruby app.. fun thing!

Answer (score 0):

We can take an advantage of `Kernel#sprintf`, which allows us to provide a string as a template and a hash as template data:

```
sprintf("Hello %{name}", { name: "Yoda" })
=> "Hello Yoda"
```

The shorthand for `Kernel#sprintf` is `Kernel#%`:

```
"Hello %{name}" % { name: "Yoda" }
=> "Hello Yoda"
```

So now we can build a flexible template based program, with no if statements and automatic selection of format:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

templates = {
  people:
    "Some facts about %{name}. " +
    "It has a height of %{height} centimeters and a mass of %{mass}kilograms. " +
    "It was born in %{birth_year}.",

  species:
    "Some facts about the species %{name}. " +
    "It is a %{classification}. It will answer you in %{language}.",

  planets:
    "Some facts about the planet %{name}. " +
    "It has a population of %{population} habitants and a climate %{climate}. " +
    "Its diameter is %{diameter}. "
}

API_URL = "https://swapi.co/api/%{type}/%{id}/?format=json"

type = templates.keys.sample
id   = rand 1..10

body = Faraday.get(API_URL % { type: type, id: id }).body
data = JSON.parse(body)

puts templates[type] % data.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

Example output:

```
Some facts about the species Wookiee. It is a mammal. 
It will answer you in Shyriiwook.
```